# The method connection() is undefined for the type Session

Tags: mysql, hibernate

> The method connection() is undefined for the type Session

I got this error when i am using prepared statement in Hibernate 5.2.2.

**Issue:**

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
session.beginTransaction();
PreparedStatement statement=session.connection().prepareStatement("INSERT INTO registration values (?,?,?)");
```

I got error in connection().I changed the hibernate version also.but i cant resolve this error.

Comment: Reda the javadoc of an older Version of hibernate: `Deprecated. (scheduled for removal in 4.x). Replacement depends on need; for doing direct JDBC stuff use doWork(org.hibernate.jdbc.Work); for opening a 'temporary Session' use (TBD).`

Answer (score 0):

The method actually does not exist. It was removed. The Hibernate 3.5 Javadoc says:

> Deprecated. (scheduled for removal in 4.x). Replacement depends on need; for doing direct JDBC stuff use doWork(org.hibernate.jdbc.Work); for opening a 'temporary Session' use (TBD).

The interface `Work` has a single method that gets a `Connection` passed:

> void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException
>
> Execute the discrete work encapsulated by this work instance using the supplied connection.

The method can be implemented using Java 8 lambdas:

```
session.doWork(() -> {
  connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO registration values (?,?,?)");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.but if i use doWork() means all my datatype modifiers has been modified as final .in my code im using inputstream.if i use inputstream as Final i cant use any methods.

Comment: InputStream inputStream = null; 
              if (filePart != null) {
                  
            inputStream = filePart.getInputStream();
        }

Comment: I don't understand why you can't use methods. Adding "final" might be a feature of your IDE that can be disabled. "final" prevents that a value is assigned to a variable a second time. I use Eclipse and simply remove the "final" in this case and do the second assignment. The assignment prevents that "final" is added again by Eclipse.